# NSNetService (bonjour) cannot find devices

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, bonjour, nsnetservice

I tried to make an app to communicate between iOS devices and I found ["Chatty"](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/), which is based on [`NSNetService`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (Bonjour) and it works on my devices. (iPad 3Gen, iPhone 4S and iPhone 5)

However, there's a problem, some devices cannot find each other if I use the "Internet Sharing" of Mac OSX to make Wifi hotspot, or connect to a b/g/n mixed 2.4GHz router, but it work perfectly if I use the hotspot of my iPhone 5.

Can you tell me why it cannot work in these routers? 
I guess that Bonjour is influenced by other routers in the room which I didn't connect, is that true?

Comment: I recommend a factory reset on your router, if possible.  We had a similar problem and it was due to the router's internal settings and security.  You can set up a password after, if you wish, that will not hurt things.

Comment: Thanks, however it does not help so much, the devices can find each other now but cannot communicate...